# Questionary and user oriented CMS with subscription support

Tags: content-management-system

I'm looking for the CMS to run subscription service.

- customer signs up and fills in preliminary question-form
- customer can subscribe to receive informations based on the question-form and other question-forms filled periodically
- admin is able to create new question-forms, send it to specific customer and based on his response send him an information
- customer can see the admin's response in his dashboard

Some of the key features are:

- user management
- subscriptions support (Paypal, payment cards)
- JSON API to connect the mobile iOS/Android application to the system
- analysis atc.

I know there are Drupal and Joomla or commerce systems like Magento. But is there any CSM that will fit my needs?

Comment: What are your needs ? Do you want to develop on it or you just want to deploy this CMS and configure it ? I think all products you quoted and their concurrents can fill your requirements, since this kind of product is made to be agile. For most of them you will find a bunch of modules/plugins to get want you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think that correctly modified WordPress would do the trick.

You will have to extend it's functionality with plugins. There are some nice ones for PayPal subscription and advanced Q forms making. Built in functionality will allow you to manage users and additional plugins of either your or others authorship will allow you to easily connect with JSON POST/GET requests depending what your specific needs are.

WordPress is very neat, has a great developing community, and you may create beautiful designs with it.

But system like Joomla is also very "customizable", with enough time spent you will have the features you need.

I'm sorry if that's not what you were looking for, but there will never be a 100% match to features you have specified.